# Sending and receiving messages with nicerf sv611 and raspberry pi

Tags: communication

I am new here but i want to send and receive messages with the nicerf sv611 (868mhz) module using raspberry pi.

i can't find much tutorials neither some documentation to start this up. Can any of you give me some pointers?

i am very thankfull

Comment: what is a `nicerf sv611`? ... are you saying that you are unable to find the datasheet for the module? ... if a datasheet is not available, then do not use the module

Comment: it is a rf transmitter and receiver (868mhz). ik have the datasheet dont know how to share it